# AWS ALB - Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, load-balancing, handshake

I am running a tomcat/java web app on aws behind an application load balancer.

I have an WebSocket endpoint set up at "/socketserver". Locally everything works, but when web app is deployed to aws, creating an websocket client through javascript
(e.g. var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://www.example.com/socketserver");
returns 404 error during Websocket handshake.

Is there any additional setup required? I heard ALB supports websockets natively. Thanks.

some things I tried:

1. creating a separate target group with path to "/socketserver", and adding additional http rule, and enabled session stickiness.
2. changing maven websocket dependency scope to provided.
3. checked access log, found 
   127.0.0.1 - - [26/Mar/2017:13:31:29 +0000] "GET /socketserver HTTP/1.1" 404 1002

Comment: Can you post the settings of your ALB?

Comment: You are sure your javascript client is trying to connect to the right URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to activate the "Stickiness" in your target group.

You'll also need to specify the transport "websocket" for all your socket.io clients.

Comment: I enabled stickiness but that didn't solve the problem for me.

Comment: I am also not using socket.io, just plain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ALB and are experiencing this problem try updating your security policy, I ran into the same problem even though it was working perfectly fine in the same setup for another website but noticed the security policy was about 1 year behind. Updating it to a newer one seems to have solved the problem.